# How to export an object from a .js file to use it in main file

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have 2 files: `bot.js` and `queue.js`
In the second file i define a variable called queue using this code:

```
const { google } = require("googleapis");
const play = require('play-dl');
const lista = []

module.exports = { lista }

module.exports = {...
}
```

In the first file i try to import the object with this code:

```
require(`./commands/queue.js`)
console.log(lista)
```

But when
And i would like to be able to use its content in the first file
How can i do that? I've seen other answers and tried their methods but couldn't make it work

Comment: you'll have to do `module.exports = { lista } ` in the second file and import it in the first file using `require("queue.js")` , if you get an import error, swap out `queue.js` with it's relative path

Comment: The `module.exports = { lista }` should be added above the existing one?
and once i add `require("queue.js")` to the first file, doing `console.log(lista)` would show the contents of lista on the console?

Comment: assuming `lista` is the object that you want to export, yes.

Comment: I just get undefined

Comment: are both the files in the same path? please show how you have imported by editing the question

Comment: The first files in on `./` and the second one is on `./commands/`

Comment: the answer has the correct syntax, please accept it if it has solved your problem

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you export the object, then require it by deconstructing from the exports

Queue.js

```js
const { google } = require("googleapis");
const play = require('play-dl');
const lista = []

module.exports = {
   lista
}
```

Bot.js

```js
const { lista } = require('path-to-queuejs-here');

console.log(lista)
// []
```